# javascript get a value based upon another in array of objects

Tags: javascript

i am trying to return a value from an array of objects in javascript,
the first object in the array is;

```
 dict=[{index:"1",caption:"AAAffterA",blurb:"stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg"}]
```

how can i return the "blurb" value(B) if i have the "caption" value(A)?
i have managed to do it the looong way but i am sure there is an easier way ?

```
A = "AAAffterA"
var result = dict.map(function(a) {return a.caption;});
key = jQuery.inArray(A,result)
B = dict[key].blurb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one function to call.

```js
var dict = [{ index: "1", caption: "AAAffterA", blurb: "stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg" }],
    a = "AAAffterA",
    b = dict.reduce(function (res, el) {
        return el.caption === a ? el.blurb : res;
    }, undefined);
alert(b);
```

Here a solution for multiple occurence:

```js
var dict = [{ index: "1", caption: "AAAffterA", blurb: "stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg" }, { index: "2", caption: "AAAffterA", blurb: "index 2 stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg" }],
    a = "AAAffterA",
    b = dict.reduce(function (res, el) {
        el.caption === a && res.push(el.blurb);
        return res;
    }, []);
alert(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

Instead of returning the `caption` and then looking it up in the `dict` again just return the `blurb` back from the map. It will return something like this
`["stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg"]`

Now, you can reduce the last two lines by just extracting the first result directly from the array that was returned. The first element of the newly created array is the string you want to return.
`["stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg"][0]` is just `stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg`

```
> dict=[{index:"1",caption:"AAAffterA",blurb:"stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg"}]
[ { index: '1',
    caption: 'AAAffterA',
    blurb: 'stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg' } ]
> dict.map ( function(a) { if (a.caption == "AAAffterA") return a.blurb } )
[ 'stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg' ]
```

Since the array may have multiple values, including nil, `filter` through this array to return non empty results and return the first non empty result using `[0]`.

```
>[ ,,,'stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg' ,,,].filter( function(a) {    
   if (a!=null) return a 
  } ) [0]
    'stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg'
```

Combine into one final function

```
> dict.map ( function(a) 
 { if (a.caption == "AAAffterA") 
     return a.blurb } 
 ).filter( function(a) { 
    if (a!=null) return a } 
  ) [0]
'stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg'
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work as my array dict has more than one object in it ,and therefore the returned array from dict.map is longer than 1 so the [0] element is not always populated, if i remove the [0] i get _,,,,,,,'stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg',,,,,,_.

Comment: Need an additional filter to the array .filter(isNotNull) and return the first element

Answer (score 0):

First, filter the array to only return the element that has the desired caption, then return that one element, if it's found:

```js
var A = "AAAffterA",
    dict = [{index:"1",caption:"AAAffterA",blurb:"stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg"}];

// Return all matches for `A`,
var results = dict.filter(function(row){ return row.caption === A; });
// Get the first result, or a error message if none are found.
var found = results.length ? results[0].blurb : "Search returned no results!";

alert(found);
```

You can loop over `results`, in case there are more than one rows found.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use jQuery ?

If so, use `$grep`

```
var dict=[{index:"1",caption:"AAAffterA",blurb:"stuff to write here asieh 1flsidg"}];

var results = $.grep(dict, function(e){ return e.caption == 'AAAffterA'; });

alert(results[0].blurb)
```

it will return an array of results that match the caption in your array